# Is threading not working properly in Nunit?

Tags: multithreading, nunit

I think that nunit isn't function properly when threading code is involved:

Here's the sample code:

```
public class multiply
{
    public Thread myThread;
    public int Counter
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    public void RunConsolePrint()
    {
        //lock(thisLock)
        //{
        Console.WriteLine("Now thread " + name + " has started");
        for (int i = 1; i<= Counter; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": count has reached " + i+ ": total count is "+Counter);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Thread " + name + " has finished");
        //}
    }
    public multiply(string pname, int pCounter)
    {
        name = pname;
        Counter = pCounter;
        myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunConsolePrint));
    }
}
```

And here's the test code:

```
[Test]
public  void Main()
{
    counter=100;

    multiply m2=new multiply("Second", counter);
    multiply m1 = new multiply("First", counter);
    m1.myThread.Start();
    m2.myThread.Start();

}
```

And the output is a sequential running of `m1` and `m2`, which means that the loop in `m1` is **always** execute first before `m2`, at least that's what my testing shows. I ran the tests a few times and I always get this.

Is this a bug? Or an expected behavior?

**If I copy the above code to a console program and run, I can see the threading effect clearly.**

I am using the test using TestDriven.net runner.

Comment: I tried executing this code and I got m1 , m2 running in a thread and able to see the output. If you increase the count (counter=100;) to higher number you could see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The exact interleaving of two or more threads cannot really be predicted.

There are a couple of factors to consider for your example. First of all each thread will execute for its quantum before (potentially) getting switched to another thread. You can't expect thread switches to happen on any special place in your code. I.e. one thread might finish before the other one is started (especially since the task is relatively short in your case).

Secondly, since you're writing to the console, the threads are synchronized on that access. This also affects the interleaving.

The result also depends on the number of available core on your machine (as well as the general load on the machine when you run the code).

In short, you cannot predict how the two threads will run.

Answer (score 1):

It's non-deterministic whether `m1` or `m2` starts executing first. If the counter executes fast enough, I wouldn't be surprised to see one of them finish before the other starts. Change the count to something very large (e.g. a million) and I'm pretty sure you'll see separate threads executing concurrently.

Any result is possible - what result are you seeing that suggests there's a bug?

Comment: I run the above test a few times, and I got consistent result-- m1 always executes first before m2

Comment: That doesn't mean there's a bug. It may well just be a quirk of scheduling. Try making the task longer.